# Set sqlite db file in windows playframework: how to set path?

Tags: sqlite, playframework

I am trying to set my sqlite db file in windows playframework with the following lines:

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:E:\\Test.db"
```

but I get the following error:

```
"Cannot connect to database [default]"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:E:/Test.db"
```

Java substitutes the path seperators correctly.